# MVC2: how to determine if actionlink points to the current page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I want to apply a class-name like "current" to an actionlink (in the master view) when it points to the current URL, in order to indicate an "on-state" in the UI. How might I do this?

UPDATE: I understand how to apply an attribute, I just need to know how to get the actionlink to know that it is pointing to the current page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it is only for visible use, I would use javascript with jQuery to quickly add a class for the 'current' link

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.mylinks').each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).attr('href') == document.URL) {
        $(this).addClass('current');
    }
  });
});


<ul>
 <li><a href="file:///C:/Users/sam/Desktop/test%20(2).html" class="mylinks">link to current page</a></li>
 <li><a href="file:///C:/Users/sam/Desktop/test%20(3).html" class="mylinks">link to other page</a></li>
 <li><a href="file:///C:/Users/sam/Desktop/test%20(4).html" class="mylinks">link to another page</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hmmm. As a big jQuery fan, I don't know why I didn't' think of this myself.

Comment: glad to have been of assistance :)

Answer (score 5):

I suspect MVC's `ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"]` would be useful for this. The RouteData has a range of key/value pairs (such as the Action mentioned here) that allow you to retrieve information about the current page and "view state" (for want of a better description) you're currently working with.